# Leiningen 2 interactive mode

Tags: clojure, leiningen

Is the "interactive" task not available anymore for leiningen 2? Is there any alternative or plugin with a similar functionality? I am using leiningen 2.0.0-preview4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll note the last paragraph probably explains what's going on:

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/leiningen/whV-VUdKSWM/O9H7cUQbGF8J

> I should note that I'm considering dropping the interactive task in
>   2.0 in favour of Jark. You may want to try it instead:
>   http://icylisper.in/jark/start.html While the upcoming Jark version
>   intends to support running lein tasks, it unfortunately appears to be
>   nonfunctional currently.

### Edit

The link that is provided gave a 404, but digging around GitHub and I found it:

http://icylisper.github.com/jark/